# How to test onClick event that is not passed as a prop

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I'm trying to test a like button, and its using redux hooks. I want to stimulate the click of the event and see if it got called. How would i go about testing for a use case like the following:

**LikeButton.tsx**

```
const { likePost, dislikePost } = storehooks();
const memoizedLike = React.useCallback((id) => likePost(id), [likePost]);
const memoizedDislike = React.useCallback((id) => dislikePost(id), [
  dislikePost,
]);

{
  props.type === "liked" && (
    <Fragment>
      <span
        style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
        onClick={() => memoizedDislike(props.postId)}
      >
        <span style={{ padding: "12px" }}>Likes {props.likeCounts}</span>
        <FavoriteIcon
          style={{ color: "red", cursor: "pointer", margin: "-7px" }}
        />
      </span>
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

**likeButton.test.tsx**

```
 it("should test onClick of liked button", () => {
        const container = mount(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <LikeButton {...mockProps} />
            </Provider>,
        );
        console.log( // this gets called which calls the redux hook. 
            container
                .find("span")
                .at(0)
                .props()
                .onClick(),
        );
        // how should i pass jest.fn() to the onClick prop ?
        
    });
```

Comment: I think i figured it out

Answer (score 0):

So i think the best practice is to make onClicks as props passed down from parent components to child.

So i had to refactor

```
type LikeButtonProps = {
    type: "liked" | "unliked";
    likeCounts: number;
    postId?: number;
    dislike?: (id: number) => void;
    like?: (id: number) => void;
};

const LikeButton: React.FC<LikeButtonProps> = (props) => {
    return (
        <Fragment>
            {props.type === "liked" && (
                <Fragment>
                    <span style={{ cursor: "pointer" }} onClick={() => props.dislike?.(props.postId!)}>
                        <span style={{ padding: "12px" }}>Likes {props.likeCounts}</span>
                        <FavoriteIcon style={{ color: "red", cursor: "pointer", margin: "-7px" }} />
                    </span>
                </Fragment>
            )}
            {props.type === "unliked" && (
                <Fragment>
                    <span onClick={() => props.like?.(props.postId!)}>
                        <span style={{ padding: "12px" }}>Likes {props.likeCounts}</span>
                        <FavoriteBorderIcon style={{ color: "red", cursor: "pointer", margin: "-7px" }} />
                    </span>
                </Fragment>
            )}
        </Fragment>
    );
};

export default LikeButton;
```

**Parent component**

```
const { likePost, dislikePost } = storehooks();
const memoizedLike = React.useCallback((id) => likePost(id), [likePost]);
const memoizedDislike = React.useCallback((id) => dislikePost(id), [dislikePost]);

{
  type === "post-buttons" &&
    (Object.entries(currentUser!).length === 0 ? (
      <Fragment>
        <span onClick={handleClickOpen}>
          <LikeButton
            like={memoizedLike}
            type="unliked"
            likeCounts={post.likeCounts}
          />
        </span>
        {openModal ? (
          <OurModal open={openModal} handleClose={handleCloseModal} />
        ) : null}
      </Fragment>
    ) : (
      <Fragment>
        {post.likedByMe === true ? (
          <LikeButton
            postId={post!.id}
            dislike={memoizedDislike}
            type="liked"
            likeCounts={post.likeCounts}
          />
        ) : (
          <LikeButton
            postId={post!.id}
            like={memoizedLike}
            type="unliked"
            likeCounts={post.likeCounts}
          />
        )}
      </Fragment>
    ));
}
```

**LikeButton.test.tsx**

```
 const mockProps2 = {
   type: "unliked",
   likeCounts: 3,
 };

 it("should test onClick of liked button", () => {
        const mockFn = jest.fn();
        const container = mount(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <LikeButton {...mockProps2} like={mockFn} />
            </Provider>,
        );

        container
            .find("span")
            .at(0)
            .simulate("click");
        expect(mockFn).toHaveBeenCalled();
        // test passes
    });
```